# rails run first query over ajax (after view is loaded)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I have pagination + parameters set up over ajax, and working properly.

However, when first loading the page, it takes a while. Is it possible to first load the view, and then load the content over ajax (just like clicking page 2 would for pagination over ajax)?

EDIT/

Is it really stupid to use a parameter conditional? Like in my controller around my query `if params[:load] == "ajax"` as well as the parts of the view that use this data. And in jquery, when the document is ready (view loaded), call the parameter with a get: `$.getScript(window.location.pathname + "?load=ajax");`
 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it quite a lot. Load the whole view first, which contains some basic layout, then load the actual important contents using ajax. So in my controller:

```
class PriceController < ApplicationController

  def price
    # do something in order to render the page price.html
  end

  def price_f
   # render the partial which contains heavy sorting of datas
   render :partial => "price_f"
  end

end
```

in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : "/price_f.html?page=1"
    success: function(data){
       $("#price_container").html(data);
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery, you should be able to just do something simple like this after the document is ready. Really, all you're doing is telling your pagination URL that you want Page 1 instead of Page 2, etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get({
    url: "/url/for/your/page/data"
  });
});
```

To get rid of the current initial page load (I would have to see your specific code to tell you exactly what to remove/change):

1. Remove whatever code is in your controller that does the query, loads the data, etc.
2. Remove the parts of your view that are then using this initial data, maybe just sticking a loading gif in there until it's replaced by your ajax data.
3. Fire the ajax request -- the page will be loaded while it waits for the controller to sort and deliver the data.

Comment: But how do I get it to stop loading my data initially and load the view? The reason it takes a while is because we're doing massive data sorting in the backend. However, I would simply like to load the view, then show a progress bar type animation while it loads the initial data.

Comment: right now I have all of my query/loading done in `def index` if I change it to `def data` and load index and point it to `data`, would that work?

Comment: but then, I'm getting a bunch of `nil` errors in my view, blah.

Comment: Is it really stupid to put a parameter conditional? Like in my controller around my query `if params[:load] == "ajax"` as well as the parts of the view that use this data. And in jquery, when the document is ready, call the parameter `?load=ajax` ???

Comment: Regarding your `nil` errors, that's why I said in step 2 that you'll need to "fix" your view to not expect these items right away. While what you're saying should work, I would lean toward putting it under a different action and keeping the `index` action limited to what comes up on your initial page view.